# How to create user profile preferences for fields visibility?

Tags: 7, entities, users

In my case every registered user should have possibility to change his profile fields visibility settings.

Selected field can be visible by all user, visible by friends or visible to no one.

I think [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module won't help me much in this scenario.
Maybe [OG](https://www.drupal.org/project/og)? I've never used it so I have no knowledge.

There is always coding way: [hook_field_access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7) but I want to avoid it if possible.

Looks like I've found one: https://www.drupal.org/project/user_field_privacy

but this not support Profile2: https://www.drupal.org/node/1398586

Integration with Profile2:

https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/miki/1601986

Other module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_privacy